# CSS para truncar textos me desconfigura la estructura row y col de Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo las siguientes clases CSS para truncar un texto cuando éste se sale de la caja:

```
.puntos {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.puntos:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Si comento estas clases, el aspecto de mi web es el que espero según la estructura de filas y columnas de Bootstrap que he definido -el color verde es algo provisional para saber por dónde anda la `col` principal izquierda en cada momento-:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si las descomento, en vez de truncar el texto para que, ocupando sólo una línea, no desborde la caja, lo que hace es extenderlo todo lo posible, y con ello también estira las cajas -como en este caso el texto es muy largo, directamente extiende la `col` para que ocupe el ancho completo-:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos bloques que veis en las imágenes son 15 por página -se generan a través de un `foreach`- y tienen la siguiente estructura HTML:

```html
<div class="row contenedor-youtube pt-4"><iframe class="youtube" width="575" height="323.5" src="<?=$enlace_youtube?>" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<!--Vídeo de YouTube-->

<div class="row pt-2">
  <!--Portada del disco, información relativa a la canción y sistema de votación-->

  <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-imagen">
    <!--Portada del disco-->
    <img class="portada img-fluid" src="<?=url_base?>/recursos/imagenes/<?=$decada?>/<?=$ano?>/<?=$nombre_foto?>.jpg" width="150" height="150">
  </div>

  <?php require("vistas/modales/imagen.html"); ?>
  <!--Modal que despliega la portada a mayor tamaño-->

  <div class="col">
    <!--Información relativa a la canción y sistema de votación-->

    <div class="row">
      <!--Información relativa a la canción (incluyendo su puesto en la clasificación)-->

      <div class="mr-3"><span class="numero" data-contador="<?=$contador?>"><?=$contador?></span></div>
      <!--Puesto en la clasificación-->

      <div class="col informacion">
        <!--Resto de la información-->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="puntos"><span id="<?=$id_cancion?>" class="cancion font-italic"><?=$titulo_cancion?></span> de <span id="<?=$id_autor?>"><a class="autor-recopilatorio" href="<?=$enlace_rym?>" target="_blank"><?=$nombre_autor?></a></span></div>
        </div>
        <!--Canción y autor-->

        <div class="row">
          <div><img class="mundo img-fluid" src="<?=url_base?>recursos/imagenes/varias/icono_mundo.png" width="18" height="18"></div>
          <div class="col pl-2">
            <div class="puntos">
              <?=$nombre_ciudad?> (
                <?=$nombre_pais?>)</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Ciudad y país-->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="puntos">Incluida en su
            <?=$tipo?> <span class="font-italic"><?=$titulo_disco?></span>
              <?=$ano_disco?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Tipo de disco, título y año (en caso de que sea la página de décadas)-->

        <div class="row">
          <!--Subestilos-->

          <div class="puntos">

            <?php foreach($subestilos as $clave => $subestilo): ?>

            <span class="boton-subestilo badge badge-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-subestilo"><?=$subestilo?> </span>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

          </div>

          <?php require("modales/sugerencias.html"); ?>
          <!--Modal con sugerencias de canciones similares-->

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row mt-1">
      <!--Sistema de votación-->

      <span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2"> <!--Estrellas-->

                                <?php if($_SESSION['conectado']): ?> <!--Si el usuario está conectado-->

                                    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?> <!--Se crea un radiobotón de 5 unidades-->

                                        <input type="radio" name="<?=$id_cancion?>" value="<?=$i?>" <?=($i == $nota) ? 'checked data-actual="true"' : 'data-actual="false"';?>><i></i> <!--Todos identificados por el id de la canción pero cada uno con un valor de 1 a 5; si el valor equivale a la $nota que está registrada en la BD, el radiobotón aparece marcado y con el data-actual con valor verdadero; de lo contrario, no aparece marcado y el data-actual será falso-->

                                    <?php endfor; ?>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                    
                            </span>

      <div class="badge badge-pill badge-warning mt-3 ml-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <?=$nota_media?>
      </div>
      <!--Nota media-->

      <div class="mt-3 ml-2"><span class="font-weight-bold"><?=$votos_web?> </span>
        <?=$coletilla?>
      </div>
      <!--Número de votos-->

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

A su vez van contenidos en una `section` -la `col` de color verde- dentro del `main`:

```html
<main class="row mt-3" data-animsition-in-class="zoom-in-sm">
  <!--Cuerpo principal de la página de recopilatorios-->

  <section class="col" style="background-color: green">
    <!--Columna con los vídeos, la información desglosada de las canciones y el sistema de votación-->

    <--Aquí irían los 15 bloques-->

  </section>
```

Que iría acompañada por otra `section` que también funciona como `col` -lo que en la primera imagen sería la mitad en blanco, que luego es empujada hacia abajo por la mitad en verde cuando ésta se expande por completo- antes de cerrar el `main`.

Es un sistema MVC, así que me resulta un poco complicado describirlo mejor...

A ver si me podéis orientar. Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es muy similar al explicado en estos hilos de SO internacional:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590045/bootstrap-4-text-truncate-class-positions-the-text-below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837170/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-breaks-layout

Sin embargo, ninguna de las soluciones propuestas me funcionan.

La única que lo hace parcialmente es la de incluir un `style="min-width: 0;"` en `<div class="col informacion">`, pero sigue habiendo casos en que el diseño se vuelve loco.

Esta solución también se explica aquí:

https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Al final he tenido que limitar también el ancho de los cuatro `<div class="row">` con un `style="max-width: 350px;"`, y así parece que se comporta como espero en todas las situaciones -para un tamaño de pantalla grande-. Otra cosa será cuando haya que visualizar la web en una tableta o móvil.